# Performing cross validation on minutely data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, cross-validation

I would like to perform cross validation on minutely data.

I tried using the `TimeSeriesSplit` method in `Scikit` learn. But it creates folds based on index.

Hence what happens is the Train fold might contain data from 
`'2017-01-01 00:00:00'` to `'2019-01-01 10:00:00'`, and the 
Test fold will have data from `'2019-01-01 10:01:00'` to `'2019-01-02 23:59:00'`.

As you can see this will not be an accurate way to perform cross validation because the hour 10 is included in train and test folds, hence it will lead to misleading results.

What i would like to achieve is perform `TimeSeriesSplit` with grouping

For example -

```
train_fold_1 - '2017-01-01 00:00:00' to '2019-01-01 23:59:00'
test_fold_1 - '2019-01-02 00:00:00' to '2019-01-02 23:59:00'

train_fold_2 - '2017-01-01 00:00:00' to '2019-01-02 23:59:00'
test_fold_2 - '2019-01-03 00:00:00' to '2019-01-03 23:59:00'
```

I have minutely data and currently using `XGBoost` for predicting every minute of tomorrow.

PFA - [a screenshot of pandas Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyW8q.png)

In both the below cases past 400 days were used to perform cross validation
For example - If we want to predict from `2019-01-01 00:00:00` to `2019-01-01 23:59:00`, we will use past `400` days till `2018-12-31 23:59:00` for performing cross validation.

The first value in below picture is MSE and the second one is standard deviation, calculated using TimeSeriesSplit from Scikit learn.

[cross validation score 1-January-2019 using TimeSeriesSplit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JP8gg.png)

[cross validation score 1-february-2019 using TimeSeriesSplit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nnxl.png)

As you can notice even when the same amount of data has been used , we still observe a huge change in the MSE and standard deviation when the date range has been changed .

Comment: How is your data organized? You just need to sort it by time, and then index splitting is fine?

Comment: My data is in range '2017-01-01 00:00:00' to '2019-02-01 23:59:00'. It has a frequency of every min. What you have suggested wouldn't that create the problem which i have mentioned ?. Kindly correct me if i am wrong. Thnx. I will post a screenshot explaining it in a min.

Comment: Show the relevant part of the code. Is it in a pandas DataFrame, a separate list from the samples or what?

Comment: @jonnor, i posted certain stuff, Hope it helps. Unfortunately, i cannot post the code itself.

Comment: Standard TimeSeriesSplit will not get the logic that you want. So you have to implement it yourself. The reason for change in std deviation is something you have to look at, could be you have trends in your data that needs to be accounted for

Comment: @jonnor, thinks for the comment. Based on your experience can you suggest how shall I perform cross validation on such a data ? . Thnx